# I hope toast can disappear immediately when fragment finish

Tags: android, toast

I hope toast can disappear immediately when fragment finish.

There is a ToastUtils Class.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToastUtils{
    private static Toast mToast;
    public static void showToast(Context context, int msg, int duration) {
        if (mToast == null) {
            mToast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
        } else {
            mToast.setText(msg);
        }
        mToast.show();
    }
    public static void showToast(Context context, String msg, int duration) {
        if (mToast == null) {
            mToast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
        } else {
            mToast.setText(msg);
        }
        mToast.show();
    }
    public static void clearToast(){
        mToast.cancel();
    }
}
```

Many people says that overriding **onStop** can solve this problem.

So I override function **onStop** in the fragment

```
@Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        ToastUtils.clearToast();
    }
```

But it gives an exception

```
08-07 14:48:50.070  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at com.shijiebang.offlinemap.utils.ToastUtils.clearToast(ToastUtils.java:30)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at com.shijiebang.offlinemap.ui.Fragment.LoginFragment.onStop(LoginFragment.java:173)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performStop(Fragment.java:1888)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:948)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1071)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStop(FragmentManager.java:1880)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5471)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3713)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3772)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680)
08-07 14:48:50.075  11178-11178/? W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I Don't know the reason. Please help!

Comment: When does the exception occur? Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Doing a quick Google search winds up with `AVUncaughtExceptionHandler` being related to AVOS Cloud

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work without error

```
public static void clearToast(MyActivity activity){
  activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
   if(mToast != null){
    if (mToast.getView().isShown())
    {
       mToast.cancel();
    }
   }
  }
}
```

call this function like this. Change `MyActivity` name to your activity.

```
clearToast(this);
```

Comment: Sorry, I use toast in a fragment. How should I do?

Comment: You have to pass you Acitivty to clearToast and use runOnUiThread. Then it will work. Here you have some info about getActivity inside fragment.

Comment: I try this solution, however it still gives a runtimeException

Answer (score 0):

Try use `hide()` method instead of `cancel()`

Comment: Sorry...I couldn't find this function